# Does Trigger.io support iOS 6?

Tags: ios, trigger.io, ios6

When trying to run my Trigger.io app on the simulator using iOS 6 beta 4 (Xcode 4.5), it aborts with the following log:

```
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.11
[   INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[   INFO] JavaScript check complete
[   INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[   INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[   INFO] Running iOS Simulator
[   INFO] Starting simulator
[   INFO] Showing log output:
[   INFO] Terminating since there is no system event server.
[   INFO] (Run the EventPump or pass the argument "-RegisterForSystemEvents" if you want to run without SpringBoard.
```

Does this only happen on the simulator or also on real devices?

The same app runs nicely on 4.x and 5.x devices and simulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On September 17 `Trigger.io` added support for iOS 6 and the new iPhone 5 screen size:

http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#v1-4-14

Answer (score 2):

iOS 6 beta 4 introduced a change to the rules for how content is loaded and displayed in web views, which at the moment breaks us.

We will absolutely do what it takes to fix this for iOS 6! However, things are obviously still changing in this area at the moment, so we're waiting until release candidates and iOS 6 itself before we jump into addressing the problem in one way or another.

@Patrick, this may mean us moving back to http schemes after all!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What side-effects could the move to http schemes have?

Comment: In the end, the best solution was actually file URLs, so no cross-domain headaches. This also allowed us to support Reload, various tricky bits of <canvas>, iOS 6 and <audio> with local media.